# Why are percentage increases and decreases not equal?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

E.g. 2/3 and 3/2 is 66% and 150%. Why is there a 16% difference between the 2 (34% and and 50%) and why does the direction of the percentage change (positive or negative change things). I can do the calculation but don't get the logic. This is probably Mathematical logic I believe?

Comment: Is this what you mean?
$$
\left(1 - \frac{2}{3}\right) - \left(\frac{3}{2} - 1\right) = \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1 \cdot 2}{3 \cdot 2} - \frac{1 \cdot 3}{2\cdot 3} = \frac{2}{6} - \frac{3}{6} = -\frac{1}{6} = -0.166 
$$

Comment: Because the 10% of 100 is 10 while the 10% of 90 is 9.

Comment: Except for my example both start off from the same base point. 100 and 90 are both different starting figures so doesn't that not prove anything?

Comment: As I tell my math classes from time to time: Increasing by 50% is not the same as reversing a 50% decrease.

Comment: $\dfrac 2 3 = 0,666 \ldots$ and $\dfrac 3 2 = 1,5$. $\dfrac 2 3 \times \dfrac 3 2 =1$ and $0,66 \times 1,5=1$. So what ? These are usual arithmetical operations. No "weird" logic here...

Comment: You start from 1 and "subtract" $\dfrac 1 3$ to get $\dfrac 2 3$. Then you start again from 1 and "add" $\dfrac 1 2$ to get $\dfrac 3 2$. The "operations" are different and the results are different...

Answer (score 1):

$2/3$ is dividing the whole (eg $100\%$) into 3 equal parts, while $3/2$ is dividing it into 2 equal parts. Since the size of the whole is the same for both fractions, whatever quantity $1/3$ is, it must be smaller than the $1/2$ quantity. Hence, for the decrease you are subtracting less than you are adding for the increase.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The starting number is not the same.

On one, you start with 2 and divide that 2 into 3 equal parts, which is 66%.

On the second one you start off with 3 (rather than 2) and you divide that 3 into 2 equal parts, which is 150%.

The key to percentages is the starting number, it becomes much simpler when you look at it that way.